# How should I change the behavior of a class's method when this class is called inside a container?

Tags: python, oop

I'll try to explain this using an analogy (they appear to be extremely useful when dealing with this kind of problems):

I have a class `Chef` which has a basic method `cook()`. I have also a container class `Restaurant` which creates and contains an instance of `Chef`, besides other things. Now, I want `Chef` to cook differently when an instance is created and contained in a `Restaurant` instance. Maybe `Restaurant` contains also a `ProfessionalOven` and I'd like `Chef`'s `cook()` to use it when he is cooking at restaurant.

What is the right approach to implementing this behavior in Python?

Comment: You should change the design. Objects shouldn't know or care about containers that contain them.

Comment: You can pass some arguments to the `Chef` that affect its behaviour.

Comment: The Restaurant can pass the Chef a cooking Strategy.

Comment: @progmatico you mean passing Chef extra arguments?

Comment: Yes I mean the same as @khelwood. I was mildly referring the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) mostly for your inspiration. An argument could be an object with many attributes. Or a different cooking function.